# Can an EM be defined as a fraction of total screen width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

Would it be possible to say something along the lines of:

`100% screen width = 20ems  -OR-  1em = 5% screen width` ?

The idea would be to have the font, and anything else specified in ems, automatically scale with the screen.

Working on a responsive layout and I am trying to avoid any explicit measurements; everything is in % to start but I'm trying to figure out an effective way to use ems as well as %. If I could fix the ratio of ems to screen width it would help.

If this is possible, what is the minimal approach? Right now I am using nothing but CSS & HTML. I would rather avoid javascript, etc. if I can.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with `em` (at least not pure css) But `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax` might be worth looking at. Here is a browser support reference. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 1):

As Hakan mentioned the viewport units would be one possibility, yet not really smart option, as the support sucks right now. The best approach to this would possibly be to set mediaqueries and then adjust your font's for different screen sizes.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      body {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
```

Here is a good explanation on the whole viewport and mediaquery topic http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html

Comment: Yup, media queries is the answer here. Viewport units won't help.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the answer. I hate using the viewport method because it feels so much clumsier than what the language should be capable of. I know that I can use Calc to set a div height to (10%-2em), so I know that CSS "knows" how many ems are in a screen width. argh. Thanks for answering though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't have a full support in current browsers, `vw` and `vw` might be what you are looking for. Check it here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Also you can try [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my earlier comment, This can't be done with `em` (at least not pure css) But `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax` might be worth looking at. Otherwise there is always media queries.

**VW Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/95aLqbfw/